# Missing modules for cx_freeze with qgis

Tags: cx-freeze

I try to make a exe file from a Python programm which use PyQt and QGis with cx_freeze.

Here's the setup.py used by cx_freeze.

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

base = None
if sys.platform == 'win32':
    base = 'Win32GUI'

options = {
    'build_exe': {
        'includes': ['atexit'],
        'excludes': ['tkinter','tcl','tk'],
        'packages': ['PyQt4.QtGui','PyQt4.Qt','qgis.core','qgis.gui','os']
    }
}

executables = [
    Executable('Open4.py', base=base)
]

setup(name='Open4',
      version='1.1',
      description='Open4 Icam',
      options=options,
      executables=executables
      )
```

When I run this script, I can see this missing modules :

```
Missing modules:
? _emx_link imported from os
? ce imported from os
? org.python.core imported from copy
? os.path imported from Open4, ajouterunevoirie, open4__main__, os, qgis.utils, shlex
? os2 imported from os
? os2emxpath imported from os
? posix imported from os
? pwd imported from posixpath
? qgis.core.QGis imported from qgis.utils
? qgis.core.QgsApplication imported from qgis.core.contextmanagers
? qgis.core.QgsExpression imported from qgis.utils
? qgis.core.QgsFeature imported from qgis
? qgis.core.QgsGeometry imported from qgis
? qgis.core.QgsMessageLog imported from qgis.utils
? qgis.core.QgsMessageOutput imported from qgis.utils
? qgis.core.QgsProject imported from qgis.utils
? qgis.gui.QgisInterface imported from qgis.utils
? qgis.gui.QgsMapCanvas imported from ui_openihm
? qgis.server imported from qgis.utils
? riscos imported from os
? riscosenviron imported from os
? riscospath imported from os
? subprocess imported from os
```

but the script makes a build folder with an exe file and DLL and PYD files.

Question : cx_freeze says that qgis.core and qgis.gui are missing modules but I can see qgis._core.pyd, qgis._gui.pyd, qgis_core.dll and qgis_gui.dll in the build folder so do this modules really  miss?

Now, when I try to run the EXE file, nothing appends but no error is reported even if I try to execute this EXE file in the console windows.

How can I solve this? Does it means that something (a module?) is missing?

Thank you for any help.

Philippe